# How to read negative number of a file with python lasio

Tags: python, io, log-ascii-standard

I have file .las and I read it with python `lasio`. But when I print the file, `lasio` read some negative numbers as `Nan`

The content of `.las` that I have is

```
> 1190.09200       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000 
   1190.24440    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1190.39680    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1190.54920    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1190.70160    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1190.85400    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1191.00640    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1191.15880    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1191.31120    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1191.46360    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1191.61600    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000 
   1191.76840    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000    -999.25000
```

This is what I did so far :

```
import lasio
import json
import numpy
import re

data = lasio.read("./tests/well/O-CMS-001_KGAS-KINT-KOIL-KWTR-PIGN-VCL-   SUWI.las")

print data
```

when I build program,  the output was like this :

```
> 'DEPT': [ 1190.092   1190.2444  1190.3968 ...,  2429.4088  2429.5612  2429.7136],
 'KGAS': [  0.  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan],
 'KINT': [  0.  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan],
 'KOIL': [  0.  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan],
```

-999.25000 read as nan. Why is it happen? How to read a negative string on `las` file? I wrote this program that works fine but not for negative integers..!! Please help me, I'm new to Python...

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: this is the code that i've try so far

Comment: It seems likely that the ``NULL`` item in the LAS file's header section is set to -999.25, and that those negative values in the data are indeed supposed to be read in as null or invalid values. If you change that line from -999.25 to some other value, then you should get rid of the ``nan`` values in the data that lasio reads in.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to lasio [version 0.9.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lasio/0.9.1) you should be able to prevent the substitution from -999.25 to `numpy.nan` with the `null_subs=False` keyword argument:

```
import lasio

data = lasio.read("./tests/well/O-CMS-001_KGAS-KINT-KOIL-KWTR-PIGN-VCL-   SUWI.las", null_subs=False)
```